# GDB [[Inferior 1 (process 2710) exited with code 06]] strange output

Tags: c, gcc, macros, gdb

I was trying to gauge the output of a C program, so I ran the debugger.

This is the program -:

```
#define swap(a, b) temp=a; a=b; b=temp;
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
        int i, j, temp;
    i = 5;
    j = 10;
    temp = 0;
    if(i > j)
        swap(i, j);
    printf("%d %d %d",  i, j, temp);
}
```

The **output** of this program is `10 0 0`. I can't see how it's possible.

I put breaks on lines 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 in GDB. This is what I get -:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pritishc/Documents/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at ProbleminC.c:7

7   i = 5;

(gdb) print i

$1 = 0

(gdb) print j

$2 = 0

(gdb) continue

Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, main () at ProbleminC.c:8

8   j = 10;

(gdb) print i

$3 = 5

(gdb) print j

$4 = 0

(gdb) print temp

$5 = 32767

(gdb) continue

Continuing.

Breakpoint 4, main () at ProbleminC.c:9

9   temp = 0;

(gdb) print i

$6 = 5

(gdb) print j

$7 = 10

(gdb) print temp

$8 = 32767

(gdb) c

Continuing.

Breakpoint 5, main () at ProbleminC.c:10

10  if(i > j)

(gdb) print i

$9 = 5

(gdb) print j

$10 = 10

(gdb) print temp

$11 = 0

(gdb) c

Continuing.

10 0 0[Inferior 1 (process 2710) exited with code 06]

(gdb) print i

No symbol "i" in current context.

(gdb)
```

What exactly does this mean? And why on Earth is it giving me such output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined the macro by saying:

```
#define swap(a, b) temp=a; a=b; b=temp;
```

The preprocessor would translate your `if` condition to:

```
if(i > j)
    temp=i;
i=j;
j=temp;
```

Change the macro to:

```
#define swap(a, b) { temp=a; a=b; b=temp; }
```

or maybe even use a `do ... while` loop:

```
#define swap(a, b) do { temp=a; a=b; b=temp; } while (0)
```

---

The exit code of `6` being observed is the return value of `printf`.  Quoting from `man 3 printf`:

```
   Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters
   printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings).
```

In your `main()` (rather make it `int main()`), add

```
return 0;
```

Comment: Also, if(i > j)   {
        swap(i, j);
    }

Comment: That makes perfect sense. It's just plain macro substitution. Only one thing left, what are "Inferior 1" and exit code 06?

Comment: Digital_Reality: I tried that. While I'm not getting 10 0 0, the swap isn't working. It gives me 5 10 0. Edit: Well it's not supposed to work now. The entire thing is under the if statement.

Comment: @TheRedBlackTree The exit code is due to lack of `return` in `main()`, that causes the return value of `printf` to be emitted.  See the edit above.